# mysql insert into with windows batch with str_to_date

Tags: mysql, batch-file

i need to `INSERT` data with date from a table to another table with windows batch (.bat).

```
SET thedate='02/02/13'
mysql -e "INSERT INTO dest select str_to_date($thedate,'%d/%m/%Y') from source" thebase -uroot -ppassword`"
```

when i drag the .bat file to cmd window, the window show my code as :

```
SET thedate='02/02/13'
mysql -e "INSERT INTO dest select str_to_date($thedate,'m/Y') from source" thebase -uroot -ppassword"
```

the `%d/%m/%Y` has changed to `m/Y` so i get null value in table dest. When i run this query directly in phpmyadmin, it run well.

I use xampp 18.1 Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows batch, the syntax for variables is `%foo%`, not `$foo`. You're probably confusing it with bash. As such:

- `$thedate` is not a variable
- `%d/%` is considered an unset `d/` variable
- the `%` in `%Y` is considered an unmatched variable delimiter and gets ignored

You can escape `%` if you duplicate it:

```
SET thedate='02/02/13'
echo %thedate%,'%%d/%%m/%%Y'
```

... prints:

```
'02/02/13','%d/%m/%Y'
```

I'd advise you against composing SQL strings through the command line interpreter if possible. It's very difficult to get it right.